# How to configure `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` on Python gRPC server?

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I noticed that a maintainer of gRPC suggested using `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` to load balance long lived gRPC streams in their video, [Using gRPC for Long-lived and Streaming RPCs - Eric Anderson, Google](https://youtu.be/Naonb2XD_2Q?t=323). I also found an implemented proposal which only lists C, Java and Go:

```
Status: Implemented
Implemented in: C, Java, Go
```

In practice, how do I use `MAX_CONNECTION_AGE` in a python server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`grpc.server()`'s `options` argument](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.server):

> options – An optional list of key-value pairs ([channel_arguments](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/glossary.html#term-channel_arguments) in
> gRPC runtime) to configure the channel.

You would use `GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONNECTION_AGE_MS`, defined in [`grpc_types.h`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.46.x/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h):

```
/** Maximum time that a channel may exist. Int valued, milliseconds.
 * INT_MAX means unlimited. */
#define GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONNECTION_AGE_MS "grpc.max_connection_age_ms"
```

For 30 days as suggested in [Using gRPC for Long-lived and Streaming RPCs - Eric Anderson, Google](https://youtu.be/Naonb2XD_2Q?t=323), `GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONNECTION_AGE_MS` should be `2592000000` (`30*24*60*60*1000`)